# I have a audio in 128kbps that was read 16KB every second, but it seems that I am getting more than 1 seconds of the music each time. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ffmpeg, node-streams

So I have a new stream to which I will push 2048 bytes of audio buffer every 128ms (i.e. 16KB every second) but I seem to have more than 1 second of data pushed to the stream. (I think so by finding ffmpeg is still streaming sound even tens of seconds after I stop pushing data in it)

When I changed it to 1024 bytes/128ms (8KB/s), the sound stop right after I stop pushing data.

Please correct me if I do anything wrong!

##### Some background story

I am using ffmpeg to stream to a rtp server. It is one-time used, so I can't stop ffmpeg and start again. I don't want to use the ZeroMQ way because of latency. The target I am trying to archive is to have the same readable stream to ffmpeg and change the audio content on the go by stop pushing chunks of previous audio file and switch to the new one.

If you know some other ways to archive the goal, I would be very pleased to know. Thank you in advance!

##### My current code

```js
const stream = new Stream.Readable();

// ...
// (send stream to ffmpeg)
// ...

fileP = fs.createReadStream(input);
fileP.on('readable', async () => {
    var chunk;
    while (previousStream && (chunk = fileP?.read(16 * 128))) {
        if (!previousStream) break;
        stream.push(chunk);
        await delay(125);
    }
});
```

Comment: Where do you tell it what the format of the data is?  ffmpeg cannot possible guess what you're sending before you send it.

Comment: @tim-roberts Oops, I indeed did not tell ffmpeg the data format, but it somehow did stream the file. I guess it just guessed it? I will go add the arguments now and reply back what I see.

Comment: @tim-roberts Adding input format doesn't do much help sadly.

Comment: What kind of file are you reading?  Are you decoding a file, or just writing raw byte blocks from the file?